# JavaFX 8 - How to change the color of the prompt text of a NOT editable combobox via CSS?

Tags: css, combobox, stylesheet, javafx-8, text-styling

The title says everything. I want to change the color of the prompt text of a not editable `combobox`, so that the text has the same color like the prompt text of a editable `combobox`.
In my CSS-file I tried to use `-fx-prompt-text-fill` in `.combo-box`, `.combo-box-base`, `.combo-box-base .text-field` and `.combo-box-base .text-input`, but nothing worked.

What styleclass do I have to use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When the `ComboBox` is not editable, there is no `TextField`, and the property `-fx-prompt-text-fill` is no longer valid, since the control displayed instead, a `ListCell`, doesn't extend `TextInputControl`.

In order to set the style of this cell, we can provide our custom styled `ListCell`:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();
    comboBox.getItems().addAll("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3");
    comboBox.setPromptText("Click to select");
    comboBox.setEditable(false);

    comboBox.setButtonCell(new ListCell(){

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty); 
            if(empty || item==null){
                // styled like -fx-prompt-text-fill:
                setStyle("-fx-text-fill: derive(-fx-control-inner-background,-30%)");
            } else {
                setStyle("-fx-text-fill: -fx-text-inner-color");
                setText(item.toString());
            }
        }

    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(comboBox), 300, 250);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi I do beleive that I m providing a better solution

First

in your CSS file create the following

```
.input .text-field {
         -fx-prompt-text-fill: #a0a0a0; // or any color you want
}
```

than in the scene builder set your combobox class to input after attaching the CSS file

That works like a sharm for me