# Javafx Not Editable Combobox prompt text style with CSS

Tags: css, javafx, combobox

I'm trying to have my not editable Combobox having a prompt text with a fill text color a bit lighter than the actual text fill color (as for a text input).

I crossed this topic that explains a solution going through an override of the button cell: [JavaFX 8 - How to change the color of the prompt text of a NOT editable combobox via CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420047/javafx-8-how-to-change-the-color-of-the-prompt-text-of-a-not-editable-combobox)

My question is pretty simple: Can we implement the mechanism described in this post but through a CSS file? I have the feeling that this is not possible, but as I'm not expert at all in CSS I wonder if I may have missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Skin` can be assigned from CSS. You could apply modifications to the `Skinnable` in the `Skin`'s constructor, which is not what `Skin`s should do.

Assigning a `PseudoClass` whenever no item is selected would be something that a `Skin` could do.

With such a pseudo-class the `buttonCell` can be styled from CSS.

```
package combobox.promptstyle;

import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxListViewSkin;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel;

// extend default ComboBox Skin
public class PromptSkin<T> extends ComboBoxListViewSkin<T> {

    private static final PseudoClass PROMPT = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("prompt");

    public PromptSkin(final ComboBox<T> comboBox) {
        super(comboBox);

        ChangeListener<Number> selectionIndexChangeListener = (observable, oldIndex, newIndex) -> {
            getNode().pseudoClassStateChanged(PROMPT, newIndex.intValue() < 0);
        };

        ChangeListener<SelectionModel> modelChangeListener = (observable, oldSelectionModel, newSelectionModel) -> {
            if (oldSelectionModel != null) {
                oldSelectionModel.selectedIndexProperty().removeListener(selectionIndexChangeListener);
            }

            if (newSelectionModel != null) {
                newSelectionModel.selectedIndexProperty().addListener(selectionIndexChangeListener);
                selectionIndexChangeListener.changed(null, null, newSelectionModel.getSelectedIndex());
            } else {
                selectionIndexChangeListener.changed(null, null, -1);
            }
        };

        comboBox.selectionModelProperty().addListener(modelChangeListener);
        modelChangeListener.changed(null, null, comboBox.getSelectionModel());
    }

}
```

Example using the skin:

```
ComboBox comboBox = ...
comboBox.setId("combo");

// set stylesheet
```

CSS stylesheet

```css
#combo {
    /* set skin to use */
    -fx-skin: 'combobox.promptstyle.PromptSkin';
}

#combo:prompt > .list-cell {
    -fx-text-fill: derive(-fx-control-inner-background,-30%);
}
```

Note that the `Skin` extends a class from the `com.sun` packages, which may be subject to change.

Comment: Wow, that's quite the change to get a simple text a bit lighter!
So, no solution so far by only changing some CSS classes, too bad :/

Comment: @Xendar: Note that if the `Skin` is available in the classpath, you can just use it in the `-fx-skin` CSS property without having to connect this with the `ComboBox` in some other way, which will result in the `prompt` pseudoclass being added/removed which allows using it in a CSS selector. I've checked if classes & pseudoclasses for the cell were different and pseudoclassed differered initially (no `:odd`/`:even` but after selecting something & clearing the selection this doesn't work)