# How to do that the value of a ColorPicker and it's label to be the same color?

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-8, color-picker

I want that the color of the text of a ColorPicker to be same as it's value; How can I achieve that?

And if that's not possible, how can I change the text color in my css? this approach didn't work :

```
.color-picker.color-picker-label{
    -fx-text-fill: #99877f;
}
```

Comment: Since ColorPicker extends ComboBoxBase, the answer in this question may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420047/javafx-8-how-to-change-the-color-of-the-prompt-text-of-a-not-editable-combobox. I would add a listener to the ColorPicker's valueProperty and when it is changed, set the text color accordingly. I would not try and do it in css, since this will not change when you pick new colors.

Comment: @MMAdams i'll be glad to do that programmatically, but what is the property that i am gonna set? clrpkr.setstyle("-fx-text-fill") has no effect

Comment: I see now that setButtonCell is only a property of ComboBox, not ComboBoxBase or ColorPicker, so the link I provided isn't helpful, sorry. I will look and see what I can find.

Comment: oh! you need a space between `.color-picker` and `.color-picker-label` that might help